# Two items per foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

Apologies if this has already been asked (I cannot find an answer) but I am using PHP and I am building a slider, but would like two images per slide, not one. So, in theory the `foreach()` needs to include two per each.

An example of the setup is as follows:

```
<?php foreach ($page->images as $image) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image->url; ?>"/> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I was thinking I could do something like a count...

```
<?php $index = 0; foreach ($page->images as $image) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image->url; ?>"/>
    <?php $index++; ?>
    <?php if ( $index % 2 == 0 && $index !=count($page->images) ) : ?>
    <li></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But I got a little confused as this would insert something every 2... not include two of whatever the foreach loop is fetching at once.

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance

Comment: if you need to loop 2 by 2, then you probably shouldn't use a `foreach` in the first place...

Comment: @Bartdude Fair enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to work this out... hopefully it will help.

```
<div class="each-slide">
<?php $index = 0; foreach ($page->images as $image) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image->url; ?>"/>
    <?php $index++; ?>
    <?php if ( $index % 2 == 0 && $index !=count($page->images) ) : ?>
        </div><div class="each-slide">
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why so complicated? Use a simple `for` loop instead:

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i<count($page->images)-1; $i+=2) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $page->images[$i]->url; ?>"/> 
    <img src="<?php echo $page->images[$i+1]->url; ?>"/> 
<?php } ?>
```

Or even more elegant, a `do/while` loop:

```
<?php $i=0; do { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $page->images[$i++]->url; ?>"/> 
    <img src="<?php echo $page->images[$i++]->url; ?>"/> 
<?php } while ($i<count($page->images)) ?>
```

Compared to using a `foreach` loop these approaches have another advantage: you do not create copies of all objects. This can make a huge difference if those objects are non-trivial.